# Forging a Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, csrf, csrf-token

I had a look at Rails' `ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection` module and couldn't find anything related to using secrets. Basically, it uses secure PRNG as a one time pad, xors, computes Base64 and embeds into HTML (form, tags). I agree that it is impossible for an attacker to guess what a PRNG generates, but nevertheless I can generate (or forge if you like)  a similar token, embed it into my "evil" form and submit. As far as understand Rails compares ( verifies) it on the backend. But I can't fully understand why it is secure. After all, I can generate my own token exactly like Rails does. Could someone clarify how the security is achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might misunderstand what this protects against, so let's first clarify what CSRF is, and what it is not. Sorry if this is not the point of confusion, might still be helpful for others, and we will get to the point afterwards.

Let's say you have an application that allows you to say transfer money with a POST request (do something that "changes state"), and uses cookie-based sessions. (Note that this is not the only case csrf might be possible, but by far the most common.) This application receives the request and performs the action. As an attacker, I can set up another application on a different domain, and get a user to visit my rogue application. It does not even have to look similar to the real one, it can be completely different, just having a user visit my rogue domain is enough. I as the attacker can then send a post to the victim application's domain, to the exact url with all the necessary parameters so that money gets transferred (the action will be performed). The victim user need not even know if this happens in xhr from javascript - or I can just properly post a form, the user gets redirected, but the harm is done.

This is affected by a few things, but the point is that cross-origin requests are not prevented by the same origin policy, only the response will not be available to the other domain - but in this case when server state changes in the victim application (like money gets transferred), the attacker might not care much about the response itself. All this needs is that the victim user that visits the attacker's page while still being logged in to the victim application. Cookies will be sent with the request regardless of the page the request is sent from, the only thing that counts is the destination domain (well, unless `samesite` is set for the cookie, but that's a different story).

Ok, so how does Rails (and similar synchronizer token solutions) prevent this? If you lok at lines 318 and 322 in the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6843cf6a94ae1efad0464381408a1c5f2f157376/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb), the token received from the user is compared to the one already stored in the session. When a user logs in, a random token is generated and stored for that particular user, for that particular session. Subsequent requests that change state (everything apart from GET) check if the token received from the client is the same that's stored in the session. If you (or an attcker) generate and send a new one, that will be different and the request will fail validation. An attacker on their own website cannot guess the correct token to send, so the attack above becomes impossible. An attacker on a different origin also cannot read the token of a user, because that is prevented by the same origin policy (the attacker can send a GET request to the victim app, but cannot read the response).

So to clarify, CSRF is not a protection against parameter tampering, which might have caused your confusion. In your own requests, if you know the token, you can change the request in any way, send any parameter, the CSRF token does not protect against this. It is against the attack outlined above.

Note that the description above is only scratching the surface, there is a lot of depth to CSRF protection, and Rails too does a little more, with some other frameworks doing a lot more to protect against less likely attacks.

Comment: > "the attacker can send a GET request to the victim app, but cannot read the response"  What do you mean by "cannot read the response"? Any GET request to any site returns an HTTP response which is readable.

Comment: Can't sessions be read or modified on a client site, say by a malicious Javascript code? This is the key point I guess.

Comment: The docs write "...the default and recommended session store - the CookieStore - which stores all session data in the cookie itself...The cookie data is cryptographically signed to make it tamper-proof. And it is also encrypted so anyone with access to it can't read its contents.".  This must be answer to why session is not modifiable on client side. And since `session[:_csrf_token]` may not be tampered by an attacker, it is secure to compare incoming csrf token with one that is stored in the session and check. Am I on the right track?

Comment: An attacker on someotherdomain.com will not be able to download a victim application page _in the context of a user_. He can download it in his own session, he doesn't even need a browser for that, but the csrf token he gets will not be valid for the victim user's session. CSRF is about making a user inadvertently perform something in a vulnerable application. In the example above, the attacker might transfer his own money, but he cannot have a user transfer their money, because he cannot forge a valid request _for the victim user_.

Comment: So in short if you have javascript running on someotherdomain.com, and perform a GET to victimapp.com, you will not get the response, unless victimapp.com specifically allows you to (by sending a CORS header, listing someotherdomain.com as allowed).

Comment: Also the session cookie is in fact signed in Rails, but that has nothing to do with CSRF. Traditionally, session contents would be stored server-side, but Rails uses encrypted and signed cookies so the application does not use server state - this is a separate issue from CSRF protection, you can disregard this to understand CSRF and think of it like the state is on the server, because it is fully unavailable to the client.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236003/discussion-between-hardfork-and-gabor-lengyel).

Comment: Rephrasing it, in case of CSRF, the attacker needs to use the victim user's session. The way he tries to do that is he has the victim visit his website, and then makes a request to the victim app. In that request, the user's session cookie will be sent, and the server has no good way to know if the request comes from the victim app or a rogue site like the attacker's. One weak way to know would be Referer or Origin, a much more secure way is using the CSRF token, stored in the user's session, and sent with each valid request. The attacker has no way to copy that.